# How to save files found with wildcard file & folder to the right file name on the central server with rsyslog?

Tags: rsyslog, rainerscript

I am trying to use rainerscript and rsyslog v8.38 to grab logs off my servers by both wildcard and wildcard files in wildcard folders, and then save them in the same folder structure at the far end. I have wildcards working thanks to the article [here](https://selivan.github.io/2017/02/07/rsyslog-log-forward-save-filename-handle-multi-line-failover.html), but I'm trying to extend this concept to work for the wildcard folders as well.

Currently I collect the files from the folders correctly, but once it's saved the lines from all the files are saved in to one file for each folder, named the same as the folder is, for example, if I do this on my server:

```
echo "TEST1" >> /srv/log/test-new/test.log
echo "TEST1" >> /srv/log/test-new/test-new.log
```

I end up with this on my central server:

```
# cat /srv/rsyslog/2018/HOSTNAME/10/26/test-new

<133>2018-10-26T15:32:37.975449+00:00 HOSTNAME  test-new/test.log nested-srv-logs TEST1
<133>2018-10-26T15:32:51.042633+00:00 HOSTNAME  test-new/test-new.log nested-srv-logs TEST1
```

I was hoping that I could have the files saved on the central server in the same folder structure as they were found on the sending machine, is this possible?

My config is as below, sending machine has:

```
module(load="omrelp")
module(load="omfwd")

template(name="CustomForwardFormat" type="list") {
    constant(value="<")
    property(name="pri")
    constant(value=">")
    property(name="timestamp" dateFormat="rfc3339")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="hostname")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name=".suffix")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="syslogtag" position.from="1" position.to="32")
    property(name="msg" spifno1stsp="on" )
    property(name="msg")
    constant(value="\n")
    }

ruleset(name="sendToLogserver") {
    action(type="omrelp" Target="rsyslog" Port="25014" template="CustomForwardFormat"
    queue.type="LinkedList" queue.size="10000" queue.filename="q_sendToLogserver" queue.highwatermark="9000"
    queue.lowwatermark="50" queue.maxdiskspace="500m" queue.saveonshutdown="on" action.resumeRetryCount="-1"
    action.reportSuspension="on" action.reportSuspensionContinuation="on" action.resumeInterval="10")
}

ruleset(name="sendToJsonLogserver") {
    action(type="omfwd" protocol="tcp" Target="logstash" Port="5114" template="RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format"
    queue.type="LinkedList" queue.size="10000" queue.filename="q_sendToJsonLogserver" queue.highwatermark="9000"
    queue.lowwatermark="50" queue.maxdiskspace="500m" queue.saveonshutdown="on" action.resumeRetryCount="-1"
    action.reportSuspension="on" action.reportSuspensionContinuation="on" action.resumeInterval="10")
}

input(type="imfile"
    File="/srv/log/*.log"
        Tag="srv-logs"
        Ruleset="srv_logs"
        addMetadata="on")

input(type="imfile"
    File="/srv/log/*/*.log"
        Tag="nested-srv-logs"
        Ruleset="srv_logs"
        addMetadata="on")

ruleset(name="srv_logs") {
    # http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/functions.html
          # re_extract(expr, re, match, submatch, no-found)
    set $.suffix=re_extract($!metadata!filename, "(.*)/([^/]*)", 0, 2, "unknown.log");
    if ( $programname == "nested-srv-logs" ) then {
      set $.sub-suffix=re_extract($!metadata!filename, "(.*)/([^/]*)/(.*)", 0, 2, "unknown.log");
        set $.suffix=$.sub-suffix & "/" & $.suffix;
    }
    if( $!metadata!filename contains 'json' ) then {
            call sendToJsonLogserver
    } else {
      call sendToLogserver
    }
    stop
}
```

Central server has:

```
module(load="imrelp")
input(type="imrelp" port="25014" ruleset="RemoteLogProcess")

module(load="builtin:omfile" FileOwner="syslog" FileGroup="syslog" dirOwner="syslog" dirGroup="syslog" FileCreateMode="0644" DirCreateMode="0755")

template(name="CustomForwardFormat" type="list") {
    constant(value="<")
    property(name="pri")
    constant(value=">")
    property(name="timestamp" dateFormat="rfc3339")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="hostname")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name=".suffix")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="syslogtag" position.from="1" position.to="32")
    property(name="msg" spifno1stsp="on" )
    property(name="msg")
    constant(value="\n")
    }

$EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive off

template(name="FloowLogSavePath" type="list") {
    constant(value="/srv/rsyslog/")
    property(name="timegenerated" dateFormat="year")
    constant(value="/")
    property(name="hostname")
    constant(value="/")
    property(name="timegenerated" dateFormat="month")
    constant(value="/")
    property(name="timegenerated" dateFormat="day")
    constant(value="/")
    property(name="$.logpath" )
}

ruleset(name="RemoteLogProcess") {
    # For facilities local0-7 set log filename from $programname field: replace __ with /
    if ( $syslogfacility >= 16 ) then
    {
        set $.logpath = replace($programname, "__", "/");
        action(type="omfile" dynaFileCacheSize="1024" dynaFile="FloowLogSavePath" template="CustomForwardFormat"
        flushOnTXEnd="off" asyncWriting="on" flushInterval="1" ioBufferSize="64k")
    } else {
        if (($syslogfacility == 0)) then {
            set $.logpath = "kern.log";
        } else if (($syslogfacility == 1)) then {
            set $.logpath = "user";
        } else if (($syslogfacility == 2)) then {
            set $.logpath = "mail";
        } else if (($syslogfacility == 3)) then {
            set $.logpath = "daemon";
        } else if (($syslogfacility == 4) or ($syslogfacility == 10)) then {
            set $.logpath = "auth.log";
        } else if (($syslogfacility == 9) or ($syslogfacility == 15)) then {
            set $.logpath = "cron";
        } else {
            set $.logpath ="syslog";
        }
        # Built-in template RSYSLOG_FileFormat: High-precision timestamps and timezone information
        action(type="omfile" dynaFileCacheSize="1024" dynaFile="FloowLogSavePath" template="CustomForwardFormat"
        flushOnTXEnd="off" asyncWriting="on" flushInterval="1" ioBufferSize="64k")
    }
}
```

Comment: Weren't you supposed to be using `__` instead of `/` in `set $.suffix=$.sub-suffix & "/" & $.suffix;`?

Comment: I believe rsyslog converts / to __ when it sends, when it's received there is a need to convert it back on the central server.

Comment: It does not, this is a hack I added to deal with software like nginx that can not use / in syslog tags.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find that very clear in the blog you wrote

Comment: One of the reasons why I am confused is that we're saving the filename metadata in a field called .suffix, that is in the template for both sender and receiver, but on the receiver it doesn't appear to be used. Instead we take the programname field (which before now hasn't been mentioned) and replace any _ with / to get the .logpath field, which is then used to create the filename. I see that this process works, but I don't understand how. Are some field names changed between sender and receiver? I don't see that documented anywhere

Comment: Also, when I have tried to use the .suffix field, or !metadata!filename field on the receiving machine, it doesn't seem to process any logs at all

Comment: Remember the expected message format is *<PRI> TIMESTAMP HOST TAG MSG...* typically with a space between each part; there are no field names as such. rsyslog tries to parses this line and sets *properties* (variables) like hostname and tag to appropriate values.
The programname property is explained [here](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/properties.html). It is automatically extracted from the tag part of the message. By default it ends on any "/" and several other chars.  You can use `global(parser.permitSlashInProgramName="on")` to allow "/" in programname.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix it, I got rid of all the logpath and suffix parts and just used the syslogtag for the filename :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking my config, my previous answer was incorrect, in order to get wildcard folders working correctly I did the following:

Sender:

```
input(type="imfile"
    File="/srv/log/*.log"
    Tag="srv-logs"
    Ruleset="send_sorted"
    addMetadata="on")

input(type="imfile"
    File="/srv/log/*/*.log"
    Tag="nested-srv-logs"
    Ruleset="send_sorted"
    addMetadata="on")

module(load="omrelp")

ruleset(name="send_sorted") {
    set $.suffix=substring($!metadata!filename, 9, 150);
    if( $!metadata!filename contains 'json' ) then {
      call sendToJsonLogserver
    } else {
      call sendToLogserver
    }
    stop
}

template(name="CustomForwardFormat" type="list") {
    constant(value="<")
    property(name="pri")
    constant(value=">")
    property(name="timestamp" dateFormat="rfc3339")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="hostname")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name=".suffix")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="syslogtag")
    property(name="msg" spifno1stsp="on" )
    property(name="msg")
    constant(value="\n")
    }
ruleset(name="sendToLogserver") {
    action(type="omrelp"
           target="rsyslog"
           port="25014"
           template="CustomForwardFormat"
           queue.type="LinkedList" 
           queue.size="10000"
           queue.filename="q_sendToLogserver"
           queue.highwatermark="9000"
           queue.lowwatermark="50"
           queue.maxdiskspace="500m"
           queue.saveonshutdown="on" 
           action.resumeRetryCount="-1"
           action.reportSuspension="on"
           action.reportSuspensionContinuation="on"
           action.resumeInterval="10")
}

ruleset(name="sendToJsonLogserver") {
    action(type="omfwd" 
           target="logstash" 
           protocol="tcp" 
           port="5114" 
           template="RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format"
           queue.type="LinkedList"
           queue.size="10000"
           queue.filename="q_sendToJsonLogserver"
           queue.highwatermark="9000"
           queue.lowwatermark="50"
           queue.maxdiskspace="500m" 
           queue.saveonshutdown="on"
           action.resumeRetryCount="-1"
           action.reportSuspension="on"
           action.reportSuspensionContinuation="on"
           action.resumeInterval="10")
}
```

On my central server:

```
module(load="imrelp")
input(type="imrelp" port="25014" ruleset="RemoteLogProcess")

module(load="builtin:omfile" FileOwner="syslog" FileGroup="syslog" dirOwner="syslog" dirGroup="syslog" FileCreateMode="0644" DirCreateMode="0755")

template(name="CustomForwardFormat" type="list") {
    constant(value="<")
    property(name="pri")
    constant(value=">")
    property(name="timestamp" dateFormat="rfc3339")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="hostname")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name=".suffix")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="syslogtag")
    property(name="msg" spifno1stsp="on" )
    property(name="msg")
    constant(value="\n")
    }

template(name="FloowLogSavePath" type="list") {
    constant(value="/srv/rsyslog/")
    property(name="timegenerated" dateFormat="year")
    constant(value="/")
    property(name="hostname")
    constant(value="/")
    property(name="timegenerated" dateFormat="month")
    constant(value="/")
    property(name="timegenerated" dateFormat="day")
    constant(value="/")
    property(name=".logpath")
}

template(name="extract" type="string" string="%syslogtag%")

ruleset(name="RemoteLogProcess") {
    if ( $syslogfacility >= 16 ) then
    {
        set $.logpath = exec_template("extract");
        action(type="omfile" 
               dynaFileCacheSize="1024" 
               dynaFile="FloowLogSavePath" 
               template="CustomForwardFormat"
               flushOnTXEnd="off"
               asyncWriting="on"
               flushInterval="1" 
               ioBufferSize="64k")
    } else {
        if (($syslogfacility == 0)) then {
          set $.logpath = "kern.log";
        } else if (($syslogfacility == 1)) then {
            set $.logpath = "user";
        } else if (($syslogfacility == 2)) then {
            set $.logpath = "mail";
        } else if (($syslogfacility == 3)) then {
            set $.logpath = "daemon";
        } else if (($syslogfacility == 4) or ($syslogfacility == 10)) then {
            set $.logpath = "auth.log";
        } else if (($syslogfacility == 9) or ($syslogfacility == 15)) then {
            set $.logpath = "cron";
        } else {
            set $.logpath ="syslog";
        }
        action(type="omfile"
               dynaFileCacheSize="1024"
               dynaFile="FloowLogSavePath"
               template="CustomForwardFormat"
               flushOnTXEnd="off"
               asyncWriting="on"
               flushInterval="1"
               ioBufferSize="64k")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you got space inserted here:

```
property(name=".suffix")
constant(value=" ")
property(name="syslogtag" position.from="1" position.to="32")
```

Spaces are delimiters so that may mess up your setup.

Also, you are connecting them in wrong order: `$.suffix` is file and directory name and it should go last I suppose. And you are using only 1-32 symbols from syslogtag, why?

Comment: I took the 1-32 from my old config, I did try without that but it didn't seem to help, why would a space between suffix and the tag matter? In my log line sample that I put at the top of my question you can see the whole path including folder name and file name is saved in the file where .suffix is replaced from the template, the the tag is next. On the central server I tried setting the .logpath variable by replacing on the .suffix variable I had created, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Space matters because it is field delimiter in syslog message. That is why your path is parsed as part of log message.

Comment: No I put the suffix in the log message as you recommended previously, and it appears fine, with the relative path and the filename. I don't see why having a space between suffix and syslogtag is a problem, they are 2 separate fields.